# Does Python have a module for scripting command line tasks?

Tags: python, command-line, module, automation, command

Does Python of a module adapted for scripting command line tasks?

I am interested in something that can issues commands, parse the output, especially as relates to success, failure or progress and send an email depending on the outcome.

Is there some module especially adapted for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module and check some [usage examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module).

Answer (score 2):

subprocess is good and is in the standard library.  There are other external modules that can make interfacing with command line tasks a joy.

- [pbs](https://github.com/amoffat/pbs) comes in first for most innovative API.
- [shellout](https://github.com/jbowes/shellout/blob/master/examples.py) comes in a close second.

Comment: pbs looks neat.  Very Pythonic!

Answer (score 1):

Snippet using `suprocess` and `shlex` modules:

```
def runcommand(command):
    args = shlex.split(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = p.communicate()
    return (stdoutdata, stderrdata, p.returncode)

(outdata, errdata, returncode) = runcommand('/bin/ls -hl /tmp')

outlines = outdata.splitlines()
errlines = errdata.splitlines()
```

For sending mail there are good [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples) in the library documentation.

Note that [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) will wait until process terminates. For *progress* just access Popen [pid and streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin) directly combined with [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) or [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might do what you want: https://github.com/amoffat/pbs

The documentation on the GitHub page has some good examples. Also, I haven't used this yet but have read from other people online that they really like this and consider this superior to subprocess (for whatever reason)

Cheers.